# Fail to launch tclsh from tclsh

Tags: tcl

I'm launching multiple tclsh from inside a TCL script to emulate multi threading. However the calls all fail.

I've simplified the problem down to a test where a TCL proc launches a tclsh.

```
proc launch_tcl {} {
    set cmd "tclsh script.tcl"
    set pid [ eval $cmd & ]
}
```

This produces : `invalid command name "tclsh"`

I can give following lines on the TCL prompt and they work fine.

```
    set cmd "tclsh script.tcl"
    set pid [ eval $cmd & ]
```

I have tried tclsh with full path to the binary as well with same failure.

Why does the same commands fail inside the proc?

Thanks,
Gert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Tcl syntax looks more related to shell syntax like bash or tcsh tcl is actually more closely related to Perl or PHP or Ruby. Tcl only interprets tcl code thus just typing the name of another executable does not launch that executable*.

Just like Perl or Ruby (or indeed C and C++) tcl does indeed have mechanisms to launch executables. For that you need the `exec` command:

```
exec tclsh script.tcl
```

#### Warning on how exec works:

Unlike other languages where the command to spawn external binaries accept a string, tcl's exec is more closely related to C or javascript in that it accepts structured data. If you try to do this:

```
exec "tclsh script.tcl"
```

You'll get an error complaining "tclsh script.tcl" does not exist. It will look for an executable called "tclsh script.tcl" (because unix, from the very beginning, allows program names to contain spaces). Instead you need to pass the program name and **each individual argument** separately. Similarly if you tried:

```
exec tclsh "arg1 arg2"
```

The exec command will execute tclsh and pass the string "arg1 arg2" **as the first argument**.

See the documentation of exec for more info: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm

#### What to do if you have a command in a string?

Don't store commands in strings. There's no real safe way to separate arguments in strings in tcl. Instead compose your command as a list and then use the `{*}` operator to expand the list when you call exec:

```
set cmd [list tclsh script.tcl]
exec {*}$cmd
```

> *Note: There may be confusion about this because in interactive mode tcl DOES indeed launch executables if you type it. But this is only a feature of interactive mode.